# Google App Engine : Lucene org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out

Tags: google-app-engine, lucene

In `Google APP engine`, I am using `Lucene 4.1`.

I am able to generate index file in local, but on the google server I am getting following exception (although the same code works fine in local machine):

```
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out:
   com.googlecode.lucene.appengine.GaeLockFactory$1@104a681
```

Here is my code:

---

```
package com.search.domain;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

import com.domain.dataobjects.Item;
import com.googlecode.lucene.appengine.GaeDirectory;
import com.googlecode.lucene.appengine.GaeLuceneUtil;


public class ItemDataIndexWriter {

public String createIndexes(){
    IndexWriter indexWriter = null;
    GaeDirectory indexDirectory = null;
try{    
        indexDirectory = new GaeDirectory();

        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_41 );

        IndexWriterConfig config = GaeLuceneUtil.getIndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_41, analyzer);//get configuration

        config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
        indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory, config);

        addToDoc(indexWriter,"test");
 }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     return e.toString();
 }
 finally{
     try {
        if(indexWriter!=null)
             indexWriter.close();
        if(indexDirectory!=null)
             indexDirectory.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }        
 }
return "Good";
}


private static void addToDoc(IndexWriter w, String item) throws IOException {

    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("item", item, Field.Store.YES));
    w.addDocument(doc);
}
}
```

---

Can anyone guide me ? what is wrong?

Comment: Check out the solr index directory, likely there is lock file remain in the index directory, and did not cleared automatically (due to some exceptions)

Answer (score 2):

Just go into `Google AppEngine administration -> Datastore viewer`, select GaeLock entity and delete all the entities, by doing that you will unlock every Lucene index that was locked for any reason.

Be careful! Probably your Datastore is fallen into a dirty state, so you must manually delete the index by removing all entries of: `LuceneIndex`, `Segment`, `SegmentHunk`, `GaeLock`.

The problem you are fallen into can happen when Lucene AppEngine is not properly configured. Check configuration instructions on [lucene-appengine site](https://code.google.com/p/lucene-appengine/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but in a test, in the cloud works pretty well.
I did this in groovy:

```
    final DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService()
    final PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(new Query())
    def list = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults())
    datastore.delete(list.collect {it.key})

    GetIndexesRequest builder = GetIndexesRequest.newBuilder().build()
    GetResponse<Index> indexes = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndexes(builder)

    for (Index index : indexes) {

        Results<ScoredDocument> result = index.search("")

        for (Document document : result) {
            index.deleteAsync(document.id)
        }
    }
```

It's supposed to clean all data in datastore and all indexes in before each test.
But throws an error in the **index.deleteAsync(document.id)** line

Comment: resolved with: LocalServiceTestHelper testHelper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalSearchServiceTestConfig())